# Can I get a public key from PGP signature?

Tags: pgp

I have a PGP signature of a known message. However, I am not sure who signed it.

Can I get the public key - or, at least, the fingerprint/other way of searching for it on a public keyserver - just from the message and a signature?

Example: I have this message/signature from here https://futureboy.us/pgp.html

```
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA1


I vote YES on this important measure.

Alan Eliasen
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
Version: GnuPG v1.4.13 (GNU/Linux)

iEYEARECAAYFAlHZCvgACgkQ5IGEtbBWdrF5HgCfc4xhT29ouAWdo1PMlyDKIfaq
pGoAoKig5sCXukrPPoKC1ZYB5CW7BzNL
=WPPL
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
```

Can I somehow find *who* signed it, just by looking at it?

Comment: Bear in mind that, while it may be possible to get the public key, you should still also verify the key itself (e.g. verify trusted third-party signatures on the key, or contact the owner out-of-band) before trusting the signature.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes. The format of the signature is defined in [RFC 4880](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880). If you decode the base-64 and interpret the data, you will find that the bytes from position 19 to 26 (inclusive) are the issuer ID in this case:

```
ID hex: E48184B5B05676B1
```

which matches the "Long key ID" behind [your link](https://futureboy.us/pgp.html). If you convert the ID to base 64, you can find it in the original signature data, because 18 bytes happen to divide evenly into 24 base 64 characters:

```
ID b64: 5IGEtbBWdrE=
Signature: iEYEARECAAYFAlHZCvgACgkQ5IGEtbBWdrF5HgCfc4xhT29ouAWdo1PMlyDKIfaq...
```

Comment: I've never studied the format of the signature and I didn't know this way to recover the KeyID, interesting Could you add the commandline to recover the LingKeyID? using base64 -d I get an "invalid input" error

Comment: @ddddavidee, no but I literally just did `b16encode(b64decode(sig))`.

Comment: FYI: I got here from google but in my test case the key ID was showing up at byte offset 24, not 19. Reading through the RFC I guess there are a couple of different versions that the "signature packet" may be encoded in. Since my application was python I ended up using `pgpy` which made it easy: `sig = pgpy.PGPSignature(); sig.decode(asciiarmored_signature); print(sig.signer);`.

Answer (score 27):

You can get all of this information from gpg if you add the `-vv` command-line switch.  (This means extra verbose.)  For example, the easiest way to get detailed information about an OpenPGP-formatted message is to simply type:

```
gpg -vv
```

And then paste the message into it (or pass a filename as an argument.)  For example, pasting in the message above gives you the following detailed and interesting information:

```
gpg: armor: BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE
gpg: armor header: Hash: SHA1
:packet 63: length 19 - gpg control packet
gpg: armor: BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE
gpg: armor header: Version: GnuPG v1.4.13 (GNU/Linux)
:literal data packet:
    mode t (74), created 0, name="",
    raw data: unknown length
gpg: original file name=''

I vote YES on this important measure.

Alan Eliasen
:signature packet: algo 17, keyid E48184B5B05676B1
    version 4, created 1373178616, md5len 0, sigclass 0x01
    digest algo 2, begin of digest 79 1e
    hashed subpkt 2 len 4 (sig created 2013-07-07)
    subpkt 16 len 8 (issuer key ID E48184B5B05676B1)
    data: [159 bits]
    data: [160 bits]
gpg: Signature made Sun 07 Jul 2013 12:30:16 AM MDT using DSA key ID B05676B1
gpg: using PGP trust model
gpg: key 92F88CF9: accepted as trusted key
gpg: key 6C77A726: accepted as trusted key
gpg: Good signature from "Alan Eliasen (http://futureboy.homeip.net/) <eliasen@mindspring.com>"
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: 402C C0D3 D527 13E3 FB7C  7103 E481 84B5 B056 76B1
gpg: textmode signature, digest algorithm SHA1
```

In that output, you can see the 16-hex-digit key id clearly:  **E48184B5B05676B1**

That will let you search for the signer in a keyserver using something like:

```
gpg --search-keys E48184B5B05676B1
```

By the way, I wrote the GPG guide that you reference, and I can assure you that I signed the above message.  :)

Comment: Also note the WARNING starting on the fourth-from-last line. While you *can* get the public key information, it's of limited value unless you can also confirm the key itself is trustworthy.

Comment: @lszi That's a very important point that bears repeating.  In the GPG guide that I wrote (the one referenced by the original poster,) I note very strongly that unless you've validated the key with its owner, you have no guarantee at all that they actually signed it.  _Anyone_ can generate a public key for _any_ e-mail address, and can post it to a keyserver.  See this section: http://futureboy.us/pgp.html#ProcedureForVerification

Answer (score 4):

Yep, I actually can. With GnuPG, for example:

```
gpg --verify file.txt
```

(with the above file)

writes, at the end

> Primary key fingerprint: 402C C0D3 D527 13E3 FB7C  7103 E481 84B5 B056
>   76B1

OpenPGP.js works too.

```
openpgp.cleartext.readArmored(

['-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----',
'Hash: SHA1',
'',
'',
'I vote YES on this important measure.',
'',
'Alan Eliasen',
'-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----',
'Version: GnuPG v1.4.13 (GNU/Linux)',
'',
'iEYEARECAAYFAlHZCvgACgkQ5IGEtbBWdrF5HgCfc4xhT29ouAWdo1PMlyDKIfaq',
'pGoAoKig5sCXukrPPoKC1ZYB5CW7BzNL',
'=WPPL',
'-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----']. join('\n')

).getSigningKeyIds()[0].toHex();
```

=>

> "e48184b5b05676b1"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

At least you can easily recover the KeyID and with that you can recover the public key from a keyserver (if the user ever uploaded it).

You can recover the KeyID using pgpdump (locally if you install it or via the website: http://www.pgpdump.net/)

For example message you posted is signed by:

> Sub: issuer key ID(sub 16)(8 bytes) Key ID - 0xE48184B5B05676B1

and finally: http://pgp.mit.edu/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0xE48184B5B05676B1 to get the Key or the key details (you can also use your gnupg installation to get the data from the commandline)

Answer (score 1):

In golang:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/openpgp/armor"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/openpgp/packet"
)

func main() {
    armored := `-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
Version: GnuPG v1.4.13 (GNU/Linux)

iEYEARECAAYFAlHZCvgACgkQ5IGEtbBWdrF5HgCfc4xhT29ouAWdo1PMlyDKIfaq
pGoAoKig5sCXukrPPoKC1ZYB5CW7BzNL
=WPPL
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
`
    block, err := armor.Decode(strings.NewReader(armored))
    fmt.Println(err, block.Type)

    reader := packet.NewReader(block.Body)
    pkt, err := reader.Next()
    fmt.Println(err)

    key, ok := pkt.(*packet.Signature)
    fmt.Println(ok)

    fmt.Printf("%X", *key.IssuerKeyId)
}
```

prints:

```
<nil> PGP SIGNATURE
<nil>
true
E48184B5B05676B1
```

https://play.golang.org/p/oluTm5kNQQS